# Does IIS Express support the web garden model?

Tags: iis-express

I develop locally using IIS express and always perf/load test my app, but I've run into some scenarios lately, especially when publishing to Windows Azure, where contention issues due to multiple servers simply cannot be simulated locally. I know IIS supports a web garden model where multiple worker processes are used to serve requests and utilize multiple processor cores more effectively. Does IIS express support this same setting? If so, where do I configure it?

Comment: I don't think it does. I tried raising the "Maximum Worker Processes" option in my Application Pool and it only ever uses the one process when I make multiple threads. (Although for multiple applications on one pool, it does spread to other worker processes.)

Answer (score 0):

It does not. Web garden and other application pool related features rely on Windows Process Activation Service and other IIS underlying mechanism which are not available for IIS Express.